# Returning value of enum

Tags: rust

I'm implementing FizzBuzz in Rust. I went from the simplest version to using an enum and I can't resolve it. I've read enums are very potent so I tried to use them to their fullest.

Here is my implementation:

```
use std::fmt;

fn main() {
    for i in 1..100 {
        println!("{}", fizzbuzz(i))
    }
}

fn fizzbuzz(value: i32) -> Answer {
    use crate::Answer::*;
    return match (value % 3, value % 5) {
        (0, 0) => FizzBuzz,
        (0, _) => Fizz,
        (_, 0) => Buzz,
        (_, _) => Nothing(value),
    };
}

enum Answer {
    FizzBuzz,
    Fizz,
    Buzz,
    Nothing(i32),
}

impl fmt::Display for Answer {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        use crate::Answer::*;
        match self {
            FizzBuzz => write!(f, "FizzBuzz"),
            Fizz => write!(f, "Fizz"),
            Buzz => write!(f, "Buzz"),
            Nothing() => write!(f, "number passed to NoBuzz"),
        }
    }
}
```

I have 2 problems:

- how to use the name of actual enum in `match self` block?
  In Java, I could use just `FizzBuzz.name()` and it would print
  `"FizzBuzz"` - is it possible in Rust?
- is it possible to print that `value` I passed to `Nothing` in `fizzbuzz` 
  function?

Comment: `return match { ... };`: don't do that, that's very unidiomatic. Instead remove `return` and the `;`.

Comment: Someone's marked this as a duplicate, but neither of the questions it points to actually address the issue on how to *return* the Enum value from a function without getting a `Cannot move` error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can derive a printable representation *for debugging purposes* with `#[derive(Debug)]`. This would let you print it out using `println!("{:?}", self)`

Example:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Answer {
    FizzBuzz,
    Fizz,
    Buzz,
    Nothing(i32),
}
```

```
match self {
    Nothing(_) -> /* ... */,
    other -> println!("{:?}", other),
}
```

However, it's much more appropriate to write a `Display` instance yourself. You'll have to do the translation (`Fizz -> "Fizz"`, etc) yourself, but then it will be in a centralized location and you can pass it to formatters like you've been doing.

To get the value out of the `Nothing`, you simply need to pattern match on it and give it a name. Instead of

```
Nothing(_) => // Do something generic
```

consider

```
Nothing(n) => // Do something that involves the number n
```

Comment: "However, it's much more appropriate to write a Display instance yourself."→ Nah, [there are crates to do that for you](https://github.com/victorporof/rust-enum-str-derive)!